# Replace Bootstrap Nav-Pills with Images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using *Twitter Bootstrap* *3.2.0* on my Page.
I have *Nav-Pills* to navigate through the Site.
Now I want to exchange the *Nav-Pills* with Images of "Buttons" which should have exactly the same effect as the *Nav-Pills*.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#media" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Media</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is this possible? If so could anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: overwrite the `nav-pills` class background color with a background image inside your own css. Technically it's a link with just a background fill color with border radius on it, look it up in the bootstrap css. Its easy to adjust that

Comment: how would I call it?

Comment: background-color: "/img/picture.jpg"; ??

Comment: for eg .glyphicon-download:before {
content: "\e026";
}  change content to background:url(...)

Comment: I would personally add a class to the `ul` and put in there the css relevant to overwrite the nav pill color. the nav-pills color is transfered from the `anchor` element (your `<a></a>`) so you might wanna start there and figure it out.

Comment: I gave the <li> a class and it worked fine. Know I need to get the Mouse Hover effect away because it overrides the Picture. Any hints?

Comment: I solved the Mouse Hover Problem with an <ul> class wich sets the Opacity to Zero. Only problem to solve now the Dotted Outline on Firefox when not Hovering the Selected tab, because this sets again the Hover Color even when not Hovering.